# When dealing with the multi-dimentional array, why the inside sentence in a loop is not executed while the counter is still proceeding?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, void

I'm working on a problem to eliminate the augmented matrix, in order to solve linear equation using linear algebra.

I'm using 2-dimentional array to deal with this problem. However I came across a problem. The function I used to eliminate is a loop, but the inside sentence is not executed while the counter is still proceeding. Therefore the whole loop cannot be finished properly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector <int> Row;
vector <vector <int> > M;

void swap(vector <vector <int> > &M, int i, vector <vector <int> > &N, int j);
void reduce(int rank, vector <vector <int> > &M);
int search_nonzero(int rank, vector <vector <int> > &M, int j);

int main(){
    cout << "plz enter the size of linear equation:";
    int rank;

    cin >> rank;
    int value = 0;;
    cout << "plz enter the value" << endl;
    for (int initial = 0; initial <= rank; ++initial){
        Row.push_back(value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= rank-1; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j <= rank; ++j){
            cout << "m[" << i+1 <<"][" << j+1 << "]:";
            cin >> value;
            Row[j] = value;
        }
        M.push_back(Row);
    }

    reduce(rank, M);

    cout << "the operated matrix is: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rank-1; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j <= rank; ++j){
            cout << M[i][j] << "   ";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }

}
```

---

```
void swap(vector <vector <int> > & M, int i, vector <vector <int> > &N, int j){
    vector <vector <int> > temp;
    temp.push_back(M[i]);
    M[i] = N[j];
    N[j] = temp[0];
}

int search_nonzero(int rank, vector <vector <int> > & M, int j){
    for (int s = rank-1; s >= 1; s--){
        if (M[s][j] != 0)
            return s;
    }
}
```

---

```
void reduce(int rank, vector <vector <int> > & M){
    for (int s = rank-1; s > 0; s--){
        for (int i = rank-s; i < rank; ++i){
            for (int j = rank-s-1; j <= rank; ++j){
                if (M[rank-s-1][rank-s-1] == 0){
                    swap(M, i-1, M, search_nonzero(rank, M, j));
                }
                else
                M[i][j] = M[i][j] - M[rank-s-1][j]*M[i][rank-s-1]/M[rank-s-1][rank-s-1];
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

The run is:

```
    plz enter the size of linear equation: 3
    plz enter the value
    m[1][1]= 4
    m[1][2]= 5
    m[1][3]= 6
    m[1][4]= 7
    m[2][1]= 5
    m[2][2]= 6
    m[2][3]= 4
    m[2][4]= 8
    m[3][1]= 1
    m[3][2]= 2
    m[3][3]= 5
    m[3][4]= 9
    the operated matrix is:
    4   5   6   7
    0   6   4   8
    0   0   5   9
```

I have used the visual studio to debug it step by step. The problem  is within the void function reduce(). When j increase, the sentence "M[ i ] [ j ] = M[ i ] [ j ] - M[ rank - s - 1 ][ j ]*M[ i ][ rank - s - 1 ] / M [ rank - s - 1 ] [ rank - s - 1 ] ;" was just executed **once** when j=0, but was not executed as j=1,j=2 and so on.

So what's the problem with my code? I guess it is due to the call-by-reference problem, in which the value of this multidimentional array when j=2 etc were not changed although the counter j change.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I copied your code. I ran it under the debugger and I saw that the line you are concerned about **was** executed each time, with j = 0, j = 1, j = 2 etc. I guess you are making a mistake in the way you use the debugger. I don't think there is much wrong with the code.

Comment: did you get the same result when you enter the same input as my run? or you can get the other result? in my sample run, each time when j++ the sentence only worked when j = 0, or j = 0 and j = 1. I used linux and visual studio under win7, but both get the same result. Thank you!

Comment: Strange, yes I entered the same data, I'm using Visual Studio under win7 too.

Comment: In my run, after I entered all input, the process is:  **1)**s = 2, i = 1, j = 0, M = (4,5,6,7)(5,6,4,8)(1,2,5,9)  **2)**s = 2, i = 1, j = 0, M = (4,5,6,7)(0,6,4,8)(1,2,5,9)  **3)**s = 2, i = 1, j = 1, M = (4,5,6,7)(0,6,4,8)(1,2,5,9) **[(0,6,4,8) should be (0,-0.25,4,8), but it didn't change]**...and so on. So I wonder the sentence inside was not executed when j increase to 1.

Comment: What you are seeing is truncation caused by integer arithmetic. The line is executing but it has no effect with the numbers you have. See my answer.

Comment: The formula must be wrong then, when j == 1, `M[i][rank-s-1] == 0`, same when j == 2. That's why executing the statement has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are doing integer arithmetic when you are clearly expecting floating point arithmetic. Change your vector to `vector <vector <double> >`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However when I changed it into **vector <vector double> >**,  it still work like the previous version. It's so strange...:(